# Organizing sound files

Tags: c#, file, audio, resources, voiceover

This question is actually a theoretical one, not about specific coding, but of the approach.

In my video game, there are a lot of phrases that protagonist is supposed to say. Now, I want to add a voiceover, so that someone will read those phrases aloud, so I can add them as sounds, not just plain text.

There are many different phrases.

So, the main question is, what's better, to have each phrase as separate sound file, or to have those phrases divided by sections (like game areas, or game actions or whatever), where each large file will contain a number of phrases. Then, in code, I'll order to play the large file not completely, but from specific time, to specific time (is it possible in WPF?).

What is important:

Time - which approach is easier to do?

Resources - which approach is easier for computer and\or visual studio compiler?

Copyright - I want to limit the possibility of end users stealing sound files.

I personally think that having a thousand of files is crazy, so it's better to use larger files that contain smaller ones. However, my friend highly recommended against it, claiming that playing large files from the middle is harder for computer and will cause problems, maybe slow down the game.

What option will you recommend? Or maybe there is another approach I didn't think of?

Thank you in advance,

Evgenie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that using seperate sound files would be easier. Then within c#, add them all to a list.

From that I think it should just be possible to call the index of each sound file, which would be easy if you keep them organised, and labeled well.